# How to make MySQL "honestly" "execute the query, without optimization, with all subqueries?

Tags: mysql, subquery, mariadb

How to make MySQL "honestly" "execute the query, without optimization, with all subqueries?
There is a SELECT query containing a subquery, if there are no records on the condition of the main query, then the subquery is not executed, it seems that the optimization of the queries is to blame.

Comment: SQL -- the language-- is inherently declarative, not procedural. When you write a query you describe the result set you require. The server is then free to use whatever techniques are appropriate to return that result set. If the query planner figures out the result set will be empty using some sort of logic, it's free to return an empty result set quickly.  Your question approaches the operation of SQL from a procedural point of view, and is therefore hard to answer. Some old versions of Oracle had a way of selecting a stupid query planner. That's not what you want, I don't think.

Comment: I would like to specify some kind of hint in the query, for example, as SQL_NO_CACHE, USE INDEX ... and other